# ssrs linked reports not updating

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a linked report in ssrs. I have made a action from the values in a Pivot matrix to another report which shows just raw data. My Pivot matrix is perfect however when I click on a value for example 9 and takes me to my raw data report I only get back 8 results. My parameters pass through fine.I ran a query in sql server to see that result did not come back in the report and that record was created on a different date than the other 8 that came back which were all created on the same date. 
Note some linking works fine if I click on the value of 10 it will bring back 10 results.

The scenario I have is the matrix has a count value of items on a particular day. For example day 1 has 10 assets sold and when I click on that value it is meant to show the 10 assets in another report. Sometimes only less will show. could this be a cache error or a coding error?
Thanks

Comment: Can you validate the 10 items are on a giving date in the database? If so are you accidentally filtering to narrow of a spectrum in your linked report...For example, are you comparing the date part only or using between from 11:59:59 AM and 12:00:00 PM?

Comment: No I have a calculated field =code.Weekdays(Fields!DATE_RECEIVED.Value,Today()). This is used in my matrix. So I have a rows group of supplier name and a column group of days received. Lets say I click on mcdonalds supplier days 7 has 10 assets it will show me only 9. The date received is 27 nov and the one missing it 1st of december